# 3 steps image - toggle - click process (incomplete)

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have an image grid with (main) images, each of which is having behind another img (logo).
The following code is supposed to do the following on any img:
Click 1: main image opacity drops = .5 for logo readability, and logo behind it is shown with opacity = 1.
Click 2: main image opacity returns to 1, and logo behind it disappears again (opacity = 0).

I am failing in getting back to the main img state (click 2), the logo remains visible and is supposed to disappear.

Any idea suggestion on what am I doing wrong?

```js
const imageWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.image-wrapper');

imageWrappers.forEach(wrapper => {
  const images = wrapper.querySelectorAll('img');
  let index = 0;

  wrapper.addEventListener('click', () => {
    index = (index + 1) % images.length;

    images.forEach((image, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        image.style.opacity = 1;
      } else if (i === (index + 1) % images.length) {
        image.style.opacity = 0.5;
      } else {
        image.style.opacity = 0;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.image-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image-wrapper .hover-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-grid">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.marctrautmann.com/files/generate/2000x520/1668082066_8k_m07_colors_wf08_3000px/transportation-40709-by-marc-trautmann.jpg" alt="Image 1">
    <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/audi-logo-2.png" class="hover-image" alt="Image 1 Hover 1">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FiB4GA5UUAAHeHl.jpg" alt="Image 2">
    <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/pr-newsroom-wp/1/2018/11/Spotify_Logo_RGB_Green.png" class="hover-image" alt="Image 2 Hover 1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you. Layout remains the same. I keep banging my head around. Perhaps I should start again

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to don't complicate it too much in JS, and just toggling CSS classes on images after clicking. CSS rules for opacity you can add to these CSS classes:

```
.image-wrapper .main-image.hidden {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.image-wrapper .hover-image.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```
const imageWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.image-wrapper');

imageWrappers.forEach(wrapper => {
  const mainImage = wrapper.querySelector('.main-image');
  const hoverImage = wrapper.querySelector('.hover-image');

  wrapper.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mainImage.classList.toggle('hidden');
    hoverImage.classList.toggle('visible');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. I keep trying to figure whats going on as code is still not working